# Anomalous Values for MODIS LST in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, remote-sensing, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I get some very big outliers when plotting MODIS LST values against Landsat LST values in Google Earth Engine. I have done the following steps:

1)Created a 'mean_LST' layer by using MODIS Terra and Aqua 'Day' LST values.

2)Upscaled the mentioned image collection to match the resolution for Landsat 8 band 10. (100m)

3)Filtered the image collection to match the acquisition dates of the Landsat Collection.

4)Reduced each image in the merged collection using reducer.mean() and plotted the 'mean_LST' values against the Landsat 'ST_B10' values using a scatter plot (After removing null values)

Can anyone please identify where exactly the issue is occurring?

I would also appreciate suggestions (If any) to improve the overall code.

NOTE: I have also tried bit-masking([Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/741ae9813283c245f46069586e93e77c)) but it does not remove the anomalous values.
To view my code and the scatter-plot, use this [Link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/4bf003a5217e2f74276964e6fc3c1352) . Or please find my code below:

```
var terraD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MOD11A1')
  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01').select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterBounds(geometry);

var aquaD = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MYD11A1')
  .filterDate('2022-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .select('LST_Day_1km')
  .filterBounds(geometry);
  
var landsatD = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2")
  .filterDate('2020-01-01', '2023-01-01')
  .select('ST_B10')
  .filterBounds(geometry)
  .map(function(img){return img.set('system:time_start', ee.Date(img.get('system:time_start')).update({hour:0, minute:0, second:0}).millis())});
  
var landsatD = landsatD.map(function (img){
    return img.multiply(0.00341802).add(149).subtract(273.15)
              .set("system:time_start", img.get("system:time_start"));
  });
  
var landSurfaceTemperatureVis = {
  min: 13000.0,
  max: 16500.0,
  palette: [
    '040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003'
  ],
};

// Function to clip each image in the ImageCollection to the ROI
var clipToROI = function(image) {
  return image.clip(geometry);
};

var clipTerra = terraD.map(clipToROI);
//Map.addLayer(clipTerra, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'TerraD');

var clipAqua = aquaD.map(clipToROI);
//Map.addLayer(clipAqua, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'AquaD');

var clipLandsat = landsatD.map(clipToROI);
//Map.addLayer(clipLandsat);

var terraDayCount = clipTerra.size().getInfo();
if (terraDayCount > 0) {
  print('MODIS Terra daytime data is available. Count:', terraDayCount);
} else {
  print('MODIS Terra daytime data is unavailable for the specified date range.');
}
//////////UPSCALE////////////////////

// Function to upscale an image using bilinear interpolation
var upscaleBilinear = function(image) {
  return image.resample('bilinear').reproject({
    crs: image.projection(),
    scale: 100  // Set the desired scale (resolution)
  });
};

// Apply bilinear interpolation to the Terra and Aqua datasets
var bilinearTerra = clipTerra.map(upscaleBilinear);
var bilinearAqua = clipAqua.map(upscaleBilinear);
print(bilinearTerra);

// Add the upscaled Terra and Aqua layers to the map with the specified visualization
//Map.addLayer(bilinearTerra, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MODIS Terra (Upscaled)');
//Map.addLayer(bilinearAqua, landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'MODIS Aqua (Upscaled)');

// Join Terra and Aqua images based on acquisition date
var join = ee.Join.inner().apply({
  primary: bilinearTerra,
  secondary: bilinearAqua,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
  })
});

//////////////////////MEAN////////////////////////

// Function to calculate the mean of Terra and Aqua images
var calculateMean = function(image) {
  // Get the Terra and Aqua images
  var terraImage = ee.Image(image.get('primary'));
  var aquaImage = ee.Image(image.get('secondary'));
  
  // Calculate the mean of Terra and Aqua images
  var meanImage = terraImage.add(aquaImage)
    .divide(2)
    .multiply(0.02)
    .subtract(273.15)
    .rename('mean_LST');
  
  // Return the mean image with the acquisition date
  return meanImage.set('system:time_start', terraImage.get('system:time_start'));
};

// Apply the calculateMean function to the joined ImageCollection
var meanCollection = ee.ImageCollection(join.map(calculateMean));

var first = meanCollection.first();
//Map.addLayer(meanCollection,  landSurfaceTemperatureVis, 'mean' );

// Add the mean LST layer to the map
//Map.addLayer(meanCollection);

var matchedCount = meanCollection.size().getInfo();
if (matchedCount > 0) {
  print('Matching Terra and Aqua LST images found. Count:', matchedCount);
} else {
  print('No matching Terra and Aqua LST images found.');
}

print(meanCollection);
print(clipTerra);
print(clipAqua);
print(clipLandsat);

/////////////////Correlation/////////////////

var meanLandsatJoin = ee.Join.inner().apply({
  primary: meanCollection,
  secondary: clipLandsat,
  condition: ee.Filter.equals({
    leftField: 'system:time_start',
    rightField: 'system:time_start'
  })
});

// Map a function to merge the bands of each matching pair into a single image.
var mergedCollection = meanLandsatJoin.map(function(image){
  var meanImage = ee.Image(image.get('primary'));
  var landsatImage = ee.Image(image.get('secondary'));
  return meanImage.addBands(landsatImage);
});

print('Size of the merged collection:', mergedCollection.size());
print(mergedCollection);

///////////////////SCATTERPLOT/////////////////////////



// Flatten the collection into a list of values.
var listOfImages = mergedCollection.toList(mergedCollection.size());

// Map over the list to get the values for the bands.
var pairedValues = listOfImages.map(function(image) {
  var img = ee.Image(image);
  var meanValue = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    geometry: geometry, 
    scale: 100, 
    maxPixels: 1e9  // Increase the maxPixels limit
  }).get('mean_LST');
  
  var lstValue = img.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(), 
    geometry: geometry, 
    scale: 100, 
    maxPixels: 1e9  // Increase the maxPixels limit
  }).get('ST_B10');
  
  // Check and remove if any value is null
   return ee.Algorithms.If(
    ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(meanValue, null), 
    null, 
    ee.Algorithms.If(
      ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(lstValue, null),
      null,
      [meanValue, lstValue]
    ))});

// Remove nulls
pairedValues = pairedValues.removeAll([null]);

// Convert the results to an array for charting.
var pairedValuesArray = ee.Array(pairedValues);

print (pairedValuesArray)

// Generate the scatter plot.
var scatterChart = ui.Chart.array.values({
  array: pairedValuesArray,
  axis: 0
})
.setSeriesNames(['ST_B10', 'mean_LST'])
.setOptions({
  title: 'Scatter plot of mean_LST vs LST_Day_1km',
  vAxis: {title: 'mean_LST'},
  hAxis: {title: 'ST_B10'},
});

// Display the chart.
print(scatterChart);
```

Comment: By using another approach, I could find out that your Modis series doesn't have any problem. You can download for Modis this CSV: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bSWGRNjUheJ7PnaOcXOImVmgD2oXNitj/view?usp=sharing . There are 879 valid means and 189 null values.

Comment: For Landsat you only have 289 means because you have to mosaic the images for a same date (filtering them by distinct dates: there are only 289 in Landsat series) before clipping them by the area geometry. At following CSV you have the values: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sr1s7Q09j4gQLqQskcP2zYW3PVyBbShT/view?usp=sharing . This is the series with anomalous values (and only one null).

Comment: As a resume, you only can have 289 (or less) paired means by the same date.

Comment: Sorry, it is 269; not 289.

Comment: That is unusual, as on the scatter plot provided in the link the outliers lie within the MODIS values. Can you please share the code? I have also realized that I cannot perform this analysis on the whole region, therefore I will have to import the mean values as CSV and perform this correlation analysis in a Python environment.

Comment: Also, do you recommend that perform Bit-Masking on the Landsat collection and MODIS collections?

Comment: Values as -123 do not exist in any area of planet. So, you should produce each corresponding mean where both images overlapping its pixels.  In these cases both series would have the same number of values (balanced) and results would be comparable (hopefully the outliers will go away). The code has been difficult for me to produce because I have had serious problems with the Internet. When I finish, I share it as an answer.

Comment: Alright. Thank you.

Comment: Hi. Is it possible for you to share the code now ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is. I was trying to speed out the process. This is the link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/900ae867bcd4e215bdd33d0a790d486f . However, I know that it doesn't work because both series are not balanced (by using a slower version of the code: see commented lines).

Comment: By the way, I would first try to produce balanced series (with the same number of pixels) for calculating the means.

Comment: Do you recommend using masking for that? For example, when I increase the study area size, I get more images in the Landsat collection because there is often more than one observation for Landsat for the same date. (Maybe because of the smaller swath size?). So, after mosaicking the Landsat images based on date, should I mask the MODIS collection before reducing the mean for both ?

Comment: I would recommend, for producing and debugging the code better for this considered area, to reduce Landsat dates range to only 5 images (Image Collections with 1, 2,  3, 2, 3 elements before doing the respective mosaic) so; 14 images for Modis. With this quantity of images you can use 'evaluate' method to add individual images to the GEE canvas and to observe where are the masked and overlapped areas in each case (you should also mask anomalous values for Landsat).

Comment: Run the following script and see why you get such strange results (mark each layer as you desire because they are all in false mode): https://code.earthengine.google.com/10fa0d354e47d8e2d3e294595cd57e6b